# Multiple Data Validation Sheet Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create 2 sheet changes based on selections from 2 data validation drop downs. I've got the first change working as needed, but I'm struggling with the second - it doesn't copy/paste cell, there are also no errors to debug.

Any help would be really appreciated!

EDITED: My original code was from a different version, here's the correct one:

```
''First Change copies another range of cells from one sheet to another       

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D17")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case ""
                With Sheets("PrintSheet")
                .Rows(16 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
                End With
            Case "New"
                Sheets("DevicePrep").Range("A1:D23").Copy Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("B16")
            Case "Re-Issued"
                Sheets("DevicePrep").Range("F1:I23").Copy Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("B16")
        End Select

    ''Second Change copies another range of cells from one sheet to another         

    If Intersect(Target, Range("D19")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case ""
                With Sheets("PrintSheet")
                .Rows(40 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
                End With
            Case "Account Management"
                Sheets("AccountManagement").Range("A1:D23").Copy Sheets("PrintSheet").Range("B40")
        End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Soo from the code itself i can't spot anything obvious, however a lot seems to be missing i.e. your declarations. Also do you have `option explicit` enabled? If not do so and run through your code using f8 and see if it all goes smoothly

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm really new to coding. The declarations are the 'dim' statements aren't they? I'm also not familiar with option explicit? Could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: Yes declarations are the `dim` statements. Option explicit is somethingyou write at the very top of your module which will force you to declare variables (or get an error)  You can enable this to be automatoc in the vb editor under tools and then tick "require variable declaration. Basically it helps you write better code and makes spotting simple errors easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word in Change events is `Target`.  `If Target.Address = "$D$17"` will cause the Change event to execute when D17 is changed.  You can then check the value of the `Target` cell.  Without specifying which cell needs to change, it will run after every change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address="$D$17" then
      Select Case Range("D17")
```

Comment: Hi Darrell, thanks for the heads up. Does this work for more than one target? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  You can have as many as you want with separate if statements.  You can use ranges with `Intersect` or `If Target.Row=` or `If Target.Column=`